# Connecting to Rails app Postgres DB using pgAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm having trouble connecting to the database for my Rails app using pgAdmin. I have the server running and I believe that my server properties are correct in pgAdmin. Here's what I have in pgAdmin server properties:

```
Name: achievenext_dev
Host: localhost
port: 3000
SSL:
Maintenance DB: postgres
username: achievenext
password: ******
Store password: true
Restore env?: true
DB Restriction: 
Service:
Connect now: true
```

And in my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: achievenext
  password: ******
  database: achievenext_dev
```

But when I try to connect pgAdmin returns this error:

> An error has occurred:
>
> Error connecting to the server: server
>   closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

But there are no errors on my server. It appears to be running fine. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a port to your `development.yml` file.  Especially if you run a windows OS.

The default port is `port:5432` and I'm not sure if specifying the `port:3000` in your pgAdminIII would cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?
I know mysql often causes problems that it will try to connect to the socket file instead of making a TCP connection.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Danny, I tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and that did not work either.

Comment: host: 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost worked for me on my mac. Thanks a lot for this tip!